# Identification for 120Vac connector?

Tags: identification, connector

I need to find some connectors that match the configuration of the one below (not cables, just connectors) but have no idea how search for it.

[image]

This is a power connector to an LED strip light.

The two bottom sockets provide mains power (120vac, verified with a multimeter) directly to the strip light, while the middle one contains no conductor.

Here's a wider view for context.

[image]

Does this connector have a standard name?

Comment: I never knew it had a name, but often used in hair dryers and consumer goods that use 1kW or so for the 2 pin version.

Comment: It's a Mickey Mouse

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/mickey-mouse-plug/s?k=mickey+mouse+plug&ref=d6k_applink_bb_marketplace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

T5 or T8 Tube Light 3 Terminal Female connector.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are just needing a few plugs, modify the receptacle and get a std pair because , you will spend more time looking to find this part in Asia as it is never sold to consumers. It is not a user repairable part and often just used on cheap disposable products.

One std part is the IEC connector for power receptacle on cables.
[image] But then finding the mating part is just as hard and you'll end up without a cost-effective solution.

So the simplest solution is buy a power extension cord and splice in your switch cable.

Or buy the cables from your LED supplier